# NSArray vs NSDictionary look up

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Which is quicker and less expensive for checking if an object already exists within a list. By using the NSArray contains object or by checking if a key already exists for an NSDictionary?

Also does the NSArray containObject selecter iterate through the whole array elements? Also what about checking if a key already exists within a dictionary? Does that require iterating through all the keys.

Finally, what is the best and quickest way to check if an object already exists within a large list of objects (of the same class).

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you sorted your array, you could do a binary search, which could be faster. Also check out NSSet, as it may just do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many values are you talking about?  The difference in speed may be irrelevant, thus making the choice be the one that makes the most sense in the code.  In fact, that should probably be the first priority, unless and until you know that there is a speed problem.

Short version: Use NSDictionary unless you have a specific need not to.

Answer (score 5):

According to the document of Collection Classes the NSDictionary is based on HashTables.  Which means if you are searching for a key in a dictionary, the time required is mush less than iterating through an array.

So, searching for a key should be o(1+numberofcollisions). where iterating through an array is o(n).  You can quick sort array then binary search it which will make the cost a lot less.  However for your buck, NSDictionary (hash table) are very cheap for searching.

From Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html)

> > Internally, a dictionary uses a hash table to organize its storage and to provide rapid access to a value given the corresponding key. However, the methods defined for dictionaries insulate you from the complexities of working with hash tables, hashing functions, or the hashed value of keys. The methods take keys directly, not in their hashed form.

Comment: Agree. From the name "dictionary" you should realize that it is faster to do the look up. Dictionary objects are all based on hash tables as from all the languages I know.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. I was surprised when one of the answers suggested that NSDictionary uses sequential access rather than random access. I did expect that hash tables are used to map between the key value and where the object is located in memory. My question now is, which is faster, binary searching an array or NSDictionary key lookup? i.e. is it worth the effort implementing a binary lookup or are NSDictionary key lookups faster.

Comment: What about NSSET containsObject, does that go through all the objects within the set or does it use some sort of hashing?

Comment: `NSArray` and `NSSet` are both implemented on top of hash tables, too. See http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5863615/603977. @plawres

Comment: Yes, but even If arrays are hashed, in order to retrieve a specific object from the array, you would need to iterate through all the elements. Because the indexes are hashed but not the actual array objects. However, for NSDictionary, you can query if the key exists which is quicker as the keys are hashed. However, if you wanted to retrieve a particular value from the dictionary, you would have to iterate through all the keys.!in my case I am doing a lookup on the keys rather than the actual dictionary values. This should be quicker. Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: Also I would be surprised if NSArrays are hashed. On other languages, arrays elements are just stored on consecutive memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the fastest way would be to sort your array when you insert an object:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;

[myArray addObject:someCustomObject];
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    // custom compare code here
}];
```

While this takes performance out of inserting an object, it would greatly increase your lookup times.

To do a binary search on a NSArray:

```
BOOL binarySearchContains(NSArray *sortedArray, id object, NSComparator comparisonBlock)
{
    // simple recursive helper function
    __block BOOL (^_binaryRecurse)(NSArray *, id, int lo, int hi) = ^BOOL(NSArray *array, id object, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int middleIndex = ((hi - lo) / 2) + lo;

        if (hi == lo || middleIndex < 0 || middleIndex >= [array count])
            return NO;

        int compareResult = (comparisonBlock(object, [array objectAtIndex:middleIndex]));

        if (compareResult < 0)
            return _binaryRecurse(array, object, lo, middleIndex - 1);
        if (compareResult > 0)
            return _binaryRecurse(array, object, middleIndex + 1, hi);

        return YES;
    };

    return _binaryRecurse(sortedArray, object, 0, [sortedArray count]);
}
```

In my tests, the `bsearch` is approximately 15 times faster than `-containsObject:`.