# Remove duplicates from a NSMutableArray with objects added in a 'for' loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Now, I've looked up on this on here and google, and it seems everyone uses `NSSet` to remove dupes. This is cool and all, but it seems that this method removes the sorting as well.

Is there 
1) A way to sort NSSet alphabetically?
2) A better way to remove dupes in `NSMutableArray` in or outside the `for` loop where I add them to the array by reading them from a `.csv` file.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to be using an `NSOrderedSet`. Here's the documentation on it:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Can `NSOrderedSet` still be used to "Feed" a `UIPickerWheel`?

Comment: And it's mutable counterpart `NSMutableOrderedSet`.

Comment: @OleB To convert an ordred set into an array, use the `array` method on the set.

Comment: How do I set it do be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: You can create a sorted array with the `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method on `NSOrderedSet`.

Comment: @SimonGermain If the set is already sorted, why call `sortedArrayUsingComparator`? Why not simply use the `array` method to get the already sorted data?

Comment: It's sorted in the manner that it keeps the order in which items have been added to it, just like an array. If you call `addObject` on an `NSMutableOrderedSet`, it'll keep the order, as opposed to a regular `NSSet`, which all that is available is `anyObject`. You can't call `objectAtIndex:` and have a reliable order. You can call `objectAtIndex:` on the `allObjects` property of an `NSSet`, but the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an [`NSOrderedSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)* from your array; using `+orderedSetWithArray:` will preserve the array's existing order. If it's not already in the correct order, you can't sort the set directly, so there's little point in using an ordered set, but you can easily construct a regular `NSSet` and sort that into another array, using `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptor:`, or even better `allObjects`, followed by any of `NSArray`'s sorting methods.

On the other hand (it's possible I'll get some nasty comments about this, but...), since `NSArray` and `NSSet` seem to [be built on top of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863510/nsset-implementation/) the same [hash table functionality](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html), you could just do this:

```
id newObj = // Acquire new object from wherever
while( newObj ){
    if( ![arrayImConstructing containsObject:newObj] ){
        [arrayImConstructing addObject:newObj]
    }
    newObj = // Acquire next object
}
```

This is basically what an ordered set has to do when you construct it anyways, and it's quite likely that your array is small enough (if you're putting it into a `UIPicker`) that you won't notice a performance difference at all. Still, **measure the two**, and then decide.

---

*`NSOrderedSet` is available on iOS > 5.0 (or OS X > 10.7).

Answer (score 0):

NSOrderedSet gives you ordering in a set.